# Load local file if no internet connection; function calls itself again and again

Tags: ios, swift, webview, reachability

This is my code, explanation is below:

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(homewebview: UIWebView) {

    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        print("Internet connection: OK")

    } else {
        print("Internet connection: FAILED")

        let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("file", ofType: "html")!
        let url: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        homewebview.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

When clicking a hyperlink `webViewDidStartLoad` will called.

When there's an internet connection it prints `Internet connection: OK`.

When there's no internet connection it should print `Internet connection: FAILED` and open `file.html`.

But when opening the local file it calls the whole function again, and again and again…like a never ending loop.

I want to check for internet connection when clicking a (hyper)link in the WebView. If there's no internet connection a local file should load in this WebView, without calling the function again.

How can I fix it? Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Loading the local file still calls the delegate method, so you see that you have no network connection while trying to load the local file and then just try to load it again.

Comment: Just noticed it myself. How can I fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't it work to add a new outlet: `@IBOutlet var checkInternetConnection: UIWebView!` and then `checkInternetConnection.loadRequest(request)`?

Comment: There's no difference when you use an outlet, only more potential for errors. Add verification for the local files URL scheme to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: What do you mean with the last sentence? Do you have an example? Is that the common way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rise a flag when you are loading a local page to skip the recursive routine.

```
var loadingLoacalPage = false
//..//
func webViewDidStartLoad(homewebview: UIWebView) {
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
            print("Internet connection: OK")

        } else {
            print("Internet connection: FAILED")

            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "No internet connection", message: "Check internet connection.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
            alert.show()

            if(!loadingLoacalPage){

            let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("file", ofType: "html")!
            let url: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
            let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            homewebview.loadRequest(request)

            loadingLoacalPage = true

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Seems to work. Thank you very much. I made a small change in you code. Please approve it.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for your help. Really clever and simple solution.